# enchant.js game creating if statement to display div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, game-engine

I want to add what I think should be an if statement to my game, so that an html div (#game-over) which is set to "display:none" will display after a certain score is exceeded.

I created a js fiddle for the game 
    `$('#game-over').show();`[here](http://jsfiddle.net/gsoc7wqw/)
You can't play the game in the fiddle so here is a live version to view as well http://spencerpopedesign.com/enemyfighter/examples/expert/shooting/index.html

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I'm unsure what you're asking. Is your question on how to do set the display mode for the #game-over div?

Comment: I'm wondering how to expose a div id of #game-over when a certain score is exceeded. The display mode is initially set to none, but must change to be shown.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your main.js file, your score is based on the `scoreLabel.score` variable.

You can create a new event listener or add one to the current frame event listener that triggers `$('#game-over').show();`

For example, update your enterframe listener with:

```
    game.rootScene.addEventListener('enterframe', function () {
        if(rand(1000) < game.frame / 20 * Math.sin(game.frame / 100) + game.frame / 20 + 50) {
            var y = rand(320);
            var omega = y < 160 ? 0.01 : -0.01;
            var enemy = new Enemy(320, y, omega);
            enemy.key = game.frame;
            enemies[game.frame] = enemy;
        }
        scoreLabel.score = game.score;

        // If score limit reached
        if(scoreLabel.score > 1000){
            $('#game-over').show();
        }

    });
```

Comment: Trying this causes the game to freeze when the score threshold is passed.

Comment: I tried this as well:                                                     `if(scoreLabel.score > 300){
            $('#game-over').show();
        } else {('#game-over').hide(); }`